# Set label size for industrial printer via PowerShell or bash

Tags: bash, powershell, printers

At the moment I am struggling with our ways of working in my place. Guys are generating sample labels which have barcode on them, due to huge number of operators they cannot use their own accounts as it defaults the settings each time, they are trying to print even though I have set print settings on printer which is Novexx 6406 6" printer.

I would like to generate or create a PowerShell or bash script which we will then run on each account via group policy, and I would like to do the following.

print speed - 4"/s
darkness -80
width-102 mm
height- 72 mm

no padding at any side so set it to 0mm for top bottom left & right
and I need the label to be going horizontal.

I'm new to bash & PowerShell so I am looking to get started & any help would be appreciated.
Forward to explain scenario better the sample labels are being printed out from web-based app in edge browser.

Any further questions needed for resolution please reach out

Searching online however to no avail

Comment: Are the workstations Windows machines?

Comment: Yes sorry we are on windows 10 yes